# Better way to represent grammar symbols in C

Tags: design, c, compiler, parsing, memory-usage

I'm trying to build a simple compiler for a subset of the C language in C. To achieve this, I needed to figure out a way to represent the grammar symbols. Basically, each symbol can either be a *"terminal"* or a *"non-terminal"*. Each *"terminal"* must be associated with a string that can be recognized by the lexer as a lexeme. My first (trivial) idea was to represent the symbols as follows:

```
enum SymbolType {
    TERMINAL,
    NONTERMINAL
} typedef SymbolType;

struct Symbol {
    SymbolType type;
    char* content;
} typedef Symbol;
```

However, for symbols that are `NONTERMINAL`, the `content` field would be completely wasted, as these don't need to be associated with a string of characters. Space would be used inefficiently.

Another idea that I had was to have a single `char*` field, of which a `NULL` value would indicate that the symbol is `NONTERMINAL` while a non-`NULL` value would mean that the symbol is `TERMINAL`. However, I'm not sure if creating a whole `struct` to store a single field is efficient either, or if the aformentioned approach could result in some problems that I failed to anticipate.

```
struct Symbol {
    char* content;
} typedef Symbol;
```

I'm not sure if this could affect the choice of the optimal way to represent the grammar symbols, but I'm planning to implement the parsing step using a top-down LL(1) parser.

I'm thinking of representing the rules as the following, but that is also subject to improvement:

```
struct Rule {
  Symbol* pleft;
  Symbol** prights;
  int rights_count
} typedef Rule;
```

Here `pleft` is a pointer to the symbol at the left side of the rule  and `prights` is an array of size `rights_count` that contains (in order) the pointers to the symbols at the right side of the rule. There is only one symbol at the left side of the rule because I'll only start with a context-free grammar, and then decide thereafter whether to scale things to also include parts of the C language that require having a context-sensitive grammar.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the space efficiency, since a complete grammar for C is small compared to, say, a large compilation unit.

Comment: "Space would be used inefficiently" - now that we have gigabytes instead of kilobytes of memory this is not as relevant as it used to be.  Write clear clean code instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What do you mean by *"instead"*? If there is a more efficient way to implement things that is also "clean" and "clear" then why not go for it? Whether you' favor code cleanliness and clearness over performance is something that has to be decided case by case rather than having a general pre-determined outcome.

Comment: @MehdiCharife Well, it is easier to make clean, well-written code faster, than making fast code clean and well-written.  Especially if this is your first compiler.

Comment: Doesn't a non-terminal still come with a content array that is a list of symbols instead of characters?

Comment: It is definitely quite easy to make these kinds of changes to a fully-working compiler. This is not a thing that you have to decide at the beginning.

Comment: @user253751 I'm trying to model the symbols independently from the grammar rules. A rule will be presented by `struct Rule` which holds a pointer to the symbol at the left side of the rule and an array of pointers to the symbols at the right side of the rule. This can make things easier when deciding to scale things up and add new production rules to the grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely should not worry about this until your compiler is working. It's completely needless and . Do whatever is easiest, then worry about the tiny memory savings later, if you still want to.

However, if you did want to do this for some reason, a memory-efficient design would be:

- Order the symbols so that all the terminals have the lowest IDs.
- Store the number of terminal symbols.
- Make an array, only that exact length, containing the strings for each symbol.

If `symbol_id < N_TERMINALS` then it's a terminal and `terminal_strings[symbol_id]` provides the string. If `symbol_id >= N_TERMINALS` then it's a non-terminal.

It seems like you don't need a `struct` for each symbol - only an ID number. Attempting to make everything into a `struct` is a symptom of OOP indoctrination :)

Comment: This.  The “what is the simplest thing I can get away with?” question, is often more helpful than you should expect in software design.